# Adding Observers to UITextField Text Changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
class LoginViewController : UIViewController {

    var loginVM :LoginViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginVM = LoginViewModel(userName: "", password: "")

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let userNameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 100, height: 44))
        userNameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        userNameTextField.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)

        let passwordTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 300, width: 100, height: 44))
        passwordTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


        self.view.addSubview(userNameTextField)
        self.view.addSubview(passwordTextField)

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("observe Value")
    }

}
```

From my understanding the observeValue function will be fired whenever I change the text of the UITextField since I have attached it to the property "text". But the observeValue is not getting fired.

UPDATE:

Can I send the editing changed event to my view model's method:

```
 loginVM = LoginViewModel(userName: "", password: "")

  userNameTextField.addTarget(loginVM, action: #selector(loginVM.userNameChanged), for: .editingChanged)



struct LoginViewModel {

    var userName :String
    var password :String

    func userNameChanged(textField :UITextField) {

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> From my understanding the observeValue function will be fired whenever I change the text of the UITextField

No, because that's not a KVO-observable property.

Always look for what's built-in for your use. The way to know that the text of a UITextField has changed is one of these:

- to give that UITextField a delegate and use the UITextFieldDelegate method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`
- to give that UITextField a target-action pair for its UIControl event `.editingChanged`

Comment: Thanks! So, what defines a KVO-observable property. How do I know if a property is KVO observable or not.

Comment: Typically the documentation will explicitly invite you to observe any KVO observable properties.